# Parameter Exception in HttpWebRequest BeginGetResponse Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, parameters, httpwebrequest

I send in my app POST request to some URL. When I send it for the first time, it´s OK, but when I call again method `SendBookingFreeCapacity()`, then I get

`ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs` in App.xaml in function `"private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)"`.

Problem is line:

```
webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetBookingFreeCapacitydResponseCallback), webRequest);
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void SendBookingFreeCapacity() {
    var url = "https://..../getFreeCapacity";

    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(
        new AsyncCallback(GetBookingFreeCapacityRequestStreamCallback), 
        webRequest);
}

private static void GetBookingFreeCapacityRequestStreamCallback(
    IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    try {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = 
            (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        string postData = string.Empty;

        System.IO.Stream postStream = 
            webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

        postData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" 
                   + "<request>" 
                   + "<login>" + Globals.Login + "</login>" 
                   + "<password>" + Globals.Password + "</password>" 
                   + "<hotId>" + htl.hotId + "</hotId>" 
                   + "<term>" 
                   + "<from>" + dayParser(Globals.PrijezdDate) + "</from>" 
                   + "<to>" + dayParser(Globals.OdjezdDate) + "</to>" 
                   + "</term>" 
                   + "</request>";

        byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        webRequest.BeginGetResponse(
            new AsyncCallback(GetBookingFreeCapacitydResponseCallback),
             webRequest); //after this I get the exception
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}

private static void GetBookingFreeCapacitydResponseCallback(
    IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    try {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest =
            (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        //some code...
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Do you have some tips what can cause it? Where is problem?

Comment: You have an unhandled exception...ok...but...WHICH exception? What's its error message?

Comment: It´s System.EventArgs. The name of the exception is: "The parameter isn´t correct" (I have this name of exception localized in my language, maybe english name is different). There is no innerException and StackTrace...

Comment: You say the problem is with a parameter of type `System.EventArgs`, yet you've posted no code that accepts or uses an `EventArgs` or `EventArgs`-derived parameter.  You're going to have to provide more detail, like that stack trace from the exception.

Comment: [stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/SUVWbn39) ... it´s weird, that when I  call the function for the first time, it´s OK, but at the second time, I get this exception... Should I have set some property (close or I don´t know) to webRequest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded the solution...create new page...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Perception I agree this is a bad post, but he is the OP.

Comment: I have some wrong code in GetBookingFreeCapacitydResponseCallback() function...my mistake...now all work fine...

Answer (score 1):

Some users experience the same issue.

[How to fix System.ArgumentException in HttpWebResponse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598666/how-to-fix-system-argumentexception-in-httpwebresponse)

In this case, the reason remains unknown.

[System.ArgumentException: [net_WebHeaderInvalidControlChars] in Windoows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116963/system-argumentexception-net-webheaderinvalidcontrolchars-in-windoows-phone)

In this case, the reason was non-ASCII character in the HTTP request header.

P.S. You should never develop on non-English OS or IDE. I'm 99% sure you get System.ArgumentException, however your "I have this name of exception localized in my language" makes both googling for solution and asking for help much more difficult.